# How to manipulate all "options" from a dropdown menu using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I'm creating a bot using **puppeteer** that needs to be able to choose an dynamic option from a dropdown menu.
But I'm new to Javascript and Puppetter as well so i really don't know if this is even possible.

I want to get all the options inside a list and then be able to select any option using indexing like this `page.click(optionsList[3]);` and then `page.click(optionsList[0]);`

The html code looks something like this:

```
<div class="parentClass">
    <!-- Each one of this divs represent an option from the dropdown menu -->
    <div data-visualcompletion="ignore-dynamic">
        <!-- <Lot of code 1 ...></> -->
    </div>
    <div data-visualcompletion="ignore-dynamic">
        <!-- <Lot of code 0 ...></> -->
    </div>
    <div data-visualcompletion="ignore-dynamic">
        <!-- <Lot of code 0 ...></> -->
    </div>
    <div data-visualcompletion="ignore-dynamic">
        <!-- <Lot of code 1 ...></> -->
    </div>
    <div data-visualcompletion="ignore-dynamic">
        <!-- <Lot of code 0 ...></> -->
    </div>
    <div data-visualcompletion="ignore-dynamic">
        <!-- <Lot of code 0 ...></> -->
    </div>
    <!-- ...and so on -->
</div>
```

As you can see the code within the divs inside the "parentClass" can vary, there are just two types (code 1 and code 0) i didn't include the complete code because is a lot, but if you need it i can add it.

Is it possible to capture all of the options (the ones with **data-visualcompletion** attribute) inside a list and the be able to select any option using indexing: `page.click(optionsList[3]);`?

I also want to get the text from each option in another list, because i imagine that the **optionsList** will store some kind of puppeteer objects representing each option from the dropdown menu or something like that. So i think I need another list **optionsText** to store the text from each option.

I have tried this  (successfully):

```
  // Fetch the parent where all categories live (must be called after click on dropdown menu)
  let parentDomCategories = await page.$(constants.cssMpCreateItemCategoryContainer);
  // Fetch all categories in a list
  let domCategories = await parentDomCategories.$$(constants.cssMpCreateItemCategoryAttr);

  // Web categories = 33 & totalCats = 33. We good to go.
  let totalCats = await page.evaluate(el => el.length, domCategories);
  console.log(`Total number of categories: ${totalCats}`);
```

But i don't know what else i can do with `domCategories`
I have searched in the web and this should print the categories:

```
  let categoriesText = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, domCategories);
  console.log(`Text?: ${categoriesText}`);
```

But i get undefined.

Of what type is `domCategories` when i run:

```
  console.log(`typeof domCategories: ${typeof domCategories}`);
```

i get object in return.

The only way to manipualte `domCategories` is through `page.evaluate`?

Is `domCategories` an ElementHandle?

```js
(async () => {

  // Launch the browser and open a new blank page
  // Configuration when using StealthPlugin 
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    // ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--enable-automation"],
  });
  // Disable Facebook notifications
  const context = await browser.defaultBrowserContext();
  await context.overridePermissions('https://www.facebook.com', ['geolocation', 'notifications']);

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://www.facebook.com/', {waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded', 'networkidle2']});

  await page.waitForSelector('input[id="email"]', {visible: true});
  await page.type(
    'input[id="email"]', "email",
  );
  await page.type(
    'input[id="pass"]', "pass",
  );

  let nav = page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.click( 'button[name="login"]' );
  await nav;

  await page.goto(
    'https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/create/item/' , {waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded', 'networkidle2']}
  );
  // click dropdown menu
  await page.click( 'div[class="xamitd3 x1pi30zi"]' );

  // Fetch the parent where all categories live (must be called after click on dropdown menu)
  let parentDomCategories = await page.$( 'div[class="x1iz1s3 x1rife3k x2ewi1q"]' );

  // Fetch all categories in a list
  let domCategories = await parentDomCategories.$$('div[data-visualcompletion="ignore-dynamic"]');


  // Facebook categories = 33 & totalCats = 33. We good to go.
  let totalCats = await page.evaluate(el => el.length, domCategories);
  console.log(`Total number of categories: ${totalCats}`);

  // Doesn't return anything
  let categoriesText = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, domCategories);
  console.log(`Text?: ${categoriesText}`);

  // object
  console.log(`typeof domCategories: ${typeof domCategories}`);


  console.log('Trying loop');
  try {
    // doesn't even enter loop
    for (let index=0; index < domCategories.lengthl; index++)
    {
      const element = domCategories[index];
      const text_ = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, element);
      console.log(text_);
    }
    console.log('\t\tSuccessed');
  }
  catch (error){
    console.log('Error in loop');
    console.log(error.message);
  }
  console.log('Finish loop');

  /* try {
    await page.evaluate(el => el.click(), domCategories);
  }
  catch (error){
    console.log('Error in clicking categories')
    console.log(error.message);
  }

  try {
    console.log('Error in indexing domCategories')
    console.log(domCategories[0]);
  }
  catch (error){
    console.log(error.message);
  } */


  await browser.close();


})();
```

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Why not give it a try using your suggested strategy? If it fails, post the attempt as a [mcve], preferably runnable, with the actual site and exact expected outcome, and someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: I can say `page.click()` only accepts a selector string as its first argument,  which is readily apparent from [the docs](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.click). if you have an element handle and want to trigger a click on it, use `await optionsList[3].click()`. See also [Puppeteer: Find element by HTML attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57691509/puppeteer-find-element-by-html-attribute/57691665#57691665) for the first part of your question.

Comment: I could get all the categories i a variable but don't know what to do next

Comment: OK, right idea. I think you're trying to click on an element with particular text. Maybe take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64626061/6243352) which shows how to do that more directly. I can't guarantee it'll work for your use case since I can't run your code, but can you try `await page.click('[data-visualcompletion="ignore-dynamic"]::-p-text(some text you want to click)')` and let me know how it goes?

Comment: In addition to the page, it'd be good to see what `constants.cssMpCreateItemCategoryContainer` is. Better to just hardcode/inline the selectors for the purposes of asking a question. It's important that the example is complete and runnable, preferably self-contained, as my answer is, so it can be executed and verified.

Comment: I added a reproducible example

Comment: I don't have a FB account so I can't help with that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to click an element by text content. You could try adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64626061/6243352) to match your use case, using an attribute selector:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.6.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<div class="parentClass">
  <div data-visualcompletion="ignore-dynamic">foo</div>
  <div data-visualcompletion="ignore-dynamic">bar</div>
  <div data-visualcompletion="ignore-dynamic">baz</div>
</div>
<script>
document.querySelectorAll(".parentClass").forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener("click", e => e.target.textContent = "clicked!");
});
</script></body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const sel = '[data-visualcompletion="ignore-dynamic"]::-p-text(bar)';
  const el = await page.waitForSelector(sel);
  await el.click();

  // or try an untrusted click if the Puppeteer click doesn't work:
  // await el.evaluate(el => el.click());

  const text = await page.$eval("::-p-text(clicked)", el => el.textContent);
  console.log(text); // => clicked!
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

If this doesn't work on your actual website, there's probably some site-specific behavior, like visibility, the element being in a shadow DOM or iframe, async loading, the server blocking you in headless mode, or one of many other edge cases. Please share the actual page if that's the case.